# Sending commands to a device, name for idiom?

Tags: arduino, communication, interpreter

Sometimes a device has commands to be sent to another device. In simple cases, I often use strings of digits and letters like

```
"123X456YG"
```

with the meaning

```
 set the value of parameter X to 123, 456 to Y, and then Go.
```

The interpretation algorithm is quite simple : process char by char, "push" the digit to build a number (`n = 10*n + ch-'0'`), execute action (and reset number) when it is a letter.

It very convenient when there are not too many different actions (and you can remember the letters), of course you may use [SCPI](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Commands_for_Programmable_Instruments) for more complicated things.

Is there a name for this (rather obvious) way to to?

Comment: May be I should write a patent application.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of *postfix notation*. It's a notation that fairly naturally falls out of anything that uses a stack.

Examples include:

**Reverse Polish Notation** -- common on programmable calculators from the late 1960s onwards.

... in which `4 3 - 5 +` results in `6` being left at the head of the stack, because the stack builds up like this:

```
 Stack     Unconsumed input
1 [      ]  4 3 - 5 +
2 [ 4    ]  3 - 5 +
3 [ 4 3  ]  - 5 +
4 [ 1    ]  5 +
5 [ 1 5  ]  +
6 [ 6    ]
```

At steps 4 and 6, the operator is executed by popping elements off the stack, then pushing the result onto the stack.

**Many stack-based programming languages** -- including [Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)) and [Postscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript). Postfix syntax is also fairly common in the world of [esoteric programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language).

If you're curious, I thoroughly recommend having a go at hand-writing Postscript. It's a fully-fledged programming language; for example, you can write a recursive Postscript program in a few bytes, to draw a fractal curve. Test it in Ghostscript. PDF is closely related to Postscript.

The language you have created differs from these in your approach to tokenisation, but at its core -- putting the operand(s) before the operator -- it's a postfix language.

You are unlikely to get a patent granted. :)

Comment: Well, it is not really stack based, as the depth is strictly limited to 1.

Comment: More precisely: I saw several programs using the same trick, so I wondered if it had a common name, so I can refer to it in the papers.  I'm familiar with stack-based languages (wrote interpreters), but not with popular techniques in the world of programming  tiny computers.